# docker-compose: how to access to redis and mysql instance in another container?

Tags: docker-compose

I have redis and mysql each running as a separate containers

How can I connect to mysql and to redis from my app container?

I need an ip, but how to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found !

add a link to redis container, for example

having a service named 'redis_container'

links:

- redis:redis_container

so each other containers can use 'redis' as host name

Wow